# Cant use jwt connect nats by my code,its doesnt work

Tags: websocket, jwt, nats.io

I want to use Nats websocket but I don't know how to get user information so I use jwt and it works but it doesn't work when I use my code to generate user jwt.

nats server cfg

```
websocket 
{
     port: 8080
     no_tls: true

         # authorization {
    #     # If this is specified, the client has to provide the same username
    #     # and password to be able to connect.
    #     # username: "my_user_name"
    #     # password: "my_password"
    #
    #     # If this is specified, the password field in the CONNECT has to
    #     # match this token.
    #     # token: "my_token"
    #
    #     # This overrides the main's authorization timeout. For consistency
    #     # with the main's authorization configuration block, this is expressed
    #     # as a number of seconds.
    #     # timeout: 2.0
    #}
   


}

# Operator named my_org
operator: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJlZDI1NTE5LW5rZXkifQ.eyJqdGkiOiI3VVkzSkNaVUlVQUU0STZJWllBQ0NZUEdDWDdQQUlHRzczQklNTzVBT1NZMjJXQ1JZWDdRIiwiaWF0IjoxNjY4NDE3NDkzLCJpc3MiOiJPQzRLV0xGNU5CQkhPVjVLRFJGS0NITFkySEpBRFNYQUg2VEJHSk1XSEFVSFg3VlVOTkNTRVdJUyIsIm5hbWUiOiJteV9vcmciLCJzdWIiOiJPQzRLV0xGNU5CQkhPVjVLRFJGS0NITFkySEpBRFNYQUg2VEJHSk1XSEFVSFg3VlVOTkNTRVdJUyIsIm5hdHMiOnsic2lnbmluZ19rZXlzIjpbIk9DUFdTV0NQSlJNMlRDUjVIVjZFNkNFVklRV09MNExLNEJPS1VQRk5DNzNJVktZM0xIN0VVRTZZIl0sImFjY291bnRfc2VydmVyX3VybCI6Im5hdHM6Ly8wLjAuMC4wOjQyMjIiLCJzeXN0ZW1fYWNjb3VudCI6IkFDU0dDWENUVFpLWlVCRkFIN1lFR01HTkhQRFRPQlRJRUdONFlHS1JWT1hXT1FOM1Y2T1NVS1Q1Iiwic3RyaWN0X3NpZ25pbmdfa2V5X3VzYWdlIjp0cnVlLCJ0eXBlIjoib3BlcmF0b3IiLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoyfX0.axLP53rM3O2R6XNMagyX4vnBoYCp7DCA2lptVlX2i4lLdbN9x5Vm4eYP-7yG7kMqDG9rPG6HmgCyYoQndqpuAw
# System Account named SYS
system_account: ACSGCXCTTZKZUBFAH7YEGMGNHPDTOBTIEGN4YGKRVOXWOQN3V6OSUKT5

# configuration of the nats based resolver
resolver {
    type: full
    # Directory in which the account jwt will be stored
    dir: './jwt'
    # In order to support jwt deletion, set to true
    # If the resolver type is full delete will rename the jwt.
    # This is to allow manual restoration in case of inadvertent deletion.
    # To restore a jwt, remove the added suffix .delete and restart or send a reload signal.
    # To free up storage you must manually delete files with the suffix .delete.
    allow_delete: false
    # Interval at which a nats-server with a nats based account resolver will compare
    # it's state with one random nats based account resolver in the cluster and if needed, 
    # exchange jwt and converge on the same set of jwt.
    interval: "2m"
    # Timeout for lookup requests in case an account does not exist locally.
    timeout: "1.9s"
}


# Preload the nats based resolver with the system account jwt.
# This is not necessary but avoids a bootstrapping system account. 
# This only applies to the system account. Therefore other account jwt are not included here.
# To populate the resolver:
# 1) make sure that your operator has the account server URL pointing at your nats servers.
#    The url must start with: "nats://" 
#    nsc edit operator --account-jwt-server-url nats://localhost:4222
# 2) push your accounts using: nsc push --all
#    The argument to push -u is optional if your account server url is set as described.
# 3) to prune accounts use: nsc push --prune 
#    In order to enable prune you must set above allow_delete to true
# Later changes to the system account take precedence over the system account jwt listed here.
resolver_preload: {
     ACSGCXCTTZKZUBFAH7YEGMGNHPDTOBTIEGN4YGKRVOXWOQN3V6OSUKT5: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJlZDI1NTE5LW5rZXkifQ.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.DTH_ubEJpwPIj2tmr1eg8nI_HgKvFFqhQ0iL17fT8iy1bJ1AR_jnXg7CKNakYQrdb4pjEBzzpMoH_mbguSdGAQ,
}
```

When i use nsc client tools its work,

```
nsc add user --account TEAM_B math
```

```
nsc generate creds -n math > math.creds
```

When i use my code it doesnt work

```
package main

import (
   "github.com/nats-io/jwt/v2"
   "github.com/nats-io/nats.go"
   "github.com/nats-io/nkeys"
   "time"
)

func main() {
   ukp, err := nkeys.CreateUser()
   if err != nil {
      return
   }
   upub, err := ukp.PublicKey()
   if err != nil {
      return
   }
   seed, err := ukp.Seed()
   if err != nil {
      return
   }
   akp, _ := nkeys.FromSeed([]byte("SAAFREANAV7DLYTGDCST76AHUOAMK7CTK5RNJWPERHWEFPR7NXEHRTHUWI"))
   userJWT := generateUserJWT(upub, akp)
   jwtAuthOption := nats.UserJWTAndSeed(userJWT, string(seed))
   nc, err := nats.Connect("nats://localhost:4222", jwtAuthOption)
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   defer nc.Close()
}

func generateUserJWT(userPublicKey string, accountSigningKey nkeys.KeyPair) (userJWT string) {
   uc := jwt.NewUserClaims(userPublicKey)
   uc.Expires = time.Now().Add(time.Hour).Unix() // expire in an hour
   var err error
   uc.IssuerAccount, err = accountSigningKey.PublicKey()
   if err != nil {
      return ""
   }
   vr := jwt.ValidationResults{}
   uc.Validate(&vr)
   if vr.IsBlocking(true) {
      panic("Generated user claim is invalid")
   }
   userJWT, err = uc.Encode(accountSigningKey)
   if err != nil {
      return ""
   }
   return
}
```

[image: account key]

here is refence

https://docs.nats.io/running-a-nats-service/nats_admin/security/jwt#create-user-jwt
https://github.com/ConnectEverything/rethink_connectivity_examples/tree/main/episode7

my code generate jwt
its panic  Authorization Violation

here is my FE code

```
import './App.css';
import {connect, jwtAuthenticator,credsAuthenticator, StringCodec} from 'nats.ws'
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

const sc = StringCodec()

function App() {
    const c=`-----BEGIN NATS USER JWT-----
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJlZDI1NTE5LW5rZXkifQ.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.6Zg8ekHENudDY2gT5hVfXomnQ1tGfHT7O__FrewjWXH3oaWPy81Qr7_U1ZzmuWPirTq4JsZjoOnV9TxmrwywCA
------END NATS USER JWT------

************************* IMPORTANT *************************
NKEY Seed printed below can be used to sign and prove identity.
NKEYs are sensitive and should be treated as secrets.

-----BEGIN USER NKEY SEED-----
SUAIRSUPV65OG3S5C66DIMLNY2IXNUSHT6QEBFMWXGBM7G3EGPJO3XHELE
------END USER NKEY SEED------


*************************************************************
`
    const [nc, setConnection] = useState(undefined)
    const [lastError, setError] = useState("")
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])
    let key = 0
    const me = {id:"dddd",name:"ff"};
    const addMessage = (err, msg) => {
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        key++;
        const {subject, reply} = msg;
        const data = sc.decode(msg.data)
        console.log("msg==",subject,' data=',data)
        const m = {subject, reply, data, key, time: new Date().toUTCString()}
        messages.unshift(m)
        const a = messages.slice(0, 10)
        messages.unshift(a)
        setMessages(a)
    }

    const who = (err,msg)=>{

        msg.respond(me)
        const {subject, reply} = msg;
        const data = sc.decode(msg.data)
        console.log("who==",subject,' data=',data)
    }
    const entered = (err,msg)=>{
        const {subject, reply} = msg;
        const data = sc.decode(msg.data)
        console.log("en==",subject,' data=',data)
    }
    const exited = (err,msg)=>{
        const {subject, reply} = msg;
        const data = sc.decode(msg.data)
        console.log("exit==",subject,' data=',data)
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(nc)
        if (nc === undefined) {
            //connect({servers: ["nats://127.0.0.1:4222"],
            connect({servers: ["ws://127.0.0.1:8083"],

             //work   //authenticator:jwtAuthenticator("eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJlZDI1NTE5LW5rZXkifQ.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.tDfuREQDIFiIOlAD1fe7jkrVPiaRSoAwcRa_e4G3AVby97XSssEN_EQCeT60WomOo1fHIFV9hgMCuPHQAaL_Ag", new TextEncoder().encode("SUALJXSMUDYDDKWMWLREDHEEBA7HZA5FJVJFVUYMELSQNT2BJJ3J665RDQ")),
             //work   //authenticator:jwtAuthenticator("eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJlZDI1NTE5LW5rZXkifQ.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.7HovnuwbJvQCjiofMLjlT_ASa2k2xA8_biCOx-KWbGcj11kptVSsFZHKqm6ppg3OM8klNvCwDNJhJHhx0U8uAQ", new TextEncoder().encode("SUACFBD4BOQ4AWR2BG5SPLOJXFIFSWPCSY3ZS25YN5KLQXD5QKBJNMUNQQ")),
             // my jwt doesn't work
                authenticator:jwtAuthenticator("eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJlZDI1NTE5LW5rZXkifQ.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.6-pWmq1QUkmDGH6pZuXSm6pgE_VgHoJjukCMIQN6p3j5vFV5YrRWO48IDzKobUm1De4wkZHgGJZiFctM2PpDAA", new TextEncoder().encode("SUAFPCMKO6X6K2Z4GHKK7OXCLI3Q7VWOCJBIROLTX6ILSW2W7HZBJEDBJ4")),
                //authenticator:credsAuthenticator(new TextEncoder().encode(c)),
                waitOnFirstConnect: true,noEcho:true,
            }).then(
                (nc) => {
                    setConnection(nc)
                    nc.subscribe('>', {callback: addMessage})
                    nc.subscribe('user.who',{callback:who})
                    nc.subscribe('user.*.entered',{callback:entered})
                    nc.subscribe('user.*.exit',{callback:exited})
                    nc.publish('user.bob@bob.com.entered',sc.encode(me))
                }
            ).catch((err) => {
                setError(err)
                console.log(lastError)
            })
        }
    })

    const state = nc ? 'connected' : "not yet con"
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1>{state}</h1>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure: did you use `nsc push` your changes after adding user `math`? You configured your nats server with a resolver configuration. This is good, but your resolver needs the account information to verify your user.

Answer (score 0):

I know that I am little late to the party, but I think I know what is the problem. You create your user jwt using a seed that is not for signing key try first `nsc edit account TEAM_B --sk SAAFREANAV7DLYTGDCST76AHUOAMK7CTK5RNJWPERHWEFPR7NXEHRTHUWI` and then generate the user jwt.